# Android intent.getStringExtra() weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am passing `String` extra's to an `Intent` which is sent to a `BroadCastReceiver`, and fetching them like:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra("type")){
        Log.i("Listener", ":"+intent.getStringExtra("type")+":");

        if (intent.getStringExtra("type") == "start"){  
            Log.i("Listener", "start");
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra("type") == "end"){    
            Log.i("Listener", "end");
        }
    }
}//end method
```

this code gives me the following output (as expected):

```
07-22 10:41:00.038: I/Listener(28678): :start:
```

What's not expected is that the second if statement never matches, even though `type` is clearly set correctly. I have seen this a couple of times, and it really is annoying me. This behaviour seems weird, as far as I can tell, I am approaching this in the right way.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `String` comparison use `equals()` and not `==`.

Change:

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("type") == "start")
{  
      Log.i("Listener", "start");
}
if (intent.getStringExtra("type") == "end")
{    
     Log.i("Listener", "end");
}
```

to

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("type").equals("start")){  
            Log.i("Listener", "start");
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra("type").equals("end")){    
            Log.i("Listener", "end");
        }
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for further info.

Comment: can't accept yet, but this does the trick. 
I feel like such a noob now, lol. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

String is not a primitive data type, so you cannot use the == operator to compare two of them. Instead, try using:

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("type").equals("start")){
```

and

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("type").equals("end")){
```